# Windows Linux Subsystem keep running and load on boot

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I managed to get the WLS installed with a working LAMP environment. Now I have noticed that if I close the terminal, apache stops running. In order for me to load sites from localhost, I need to load up a terminal and restart apache.

Is there a way I can start WLS as a background process on boot so I don't have to constantly restart apache?

Thanks

Comment: It can likely hacked into, somehow. However, the cleanest solution would be docker, or maybe a linux server (maybe in a virtual machine).

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported.

Quoting a [blog from MS](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/08/windows-subsystem-linux-windows-server/):

> What this isn’t — WSL is not a Linux server
>
> Just as with WSL on Windows Client, you can run daemons and jobs like  MySQL, PostgreSQL, sshd, etc., via an interactive shell, but **you cannot currently use WSL to run persistent Linux services, daemons, jobs, etc. as background tasks**.

I'd suggest just running the windows version of apache, if possible. Have a look at some of the [available packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache%E2%80%93MySQL%E2%80%93PHP_packages) for windows.

Another option might be running Docker on Windows, [apparently it supports Linux containers now](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers).

Comment: thanks! I will deal with it for the mean time. there are some compatibility issues between the windows and linux kernals on node-sass so to keep things consistent with my production box i will keep it this way and just deal with it.

Comment: Another option would be Hyper-V.  You could configure it to start a headless Linux VM whenever your Windows machine boots.